# Can I change the access modifiers of any parent function in Child class?

Tags: php, c++

Can I change the access modifiers of any parent function in Child class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Child classes may only "loosen" the visibility, e.g.

```
class ParentClass
{
    protected function foo() {} 
}
```

can be

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass 
{  
    public function foo() {} 
}
```

but not

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass 
{  
    private function foo() {} 
}
```

---

Apart from that, you can use the Reflection API to change Visibility at runtime:

- [`ReflectionMethod::setAccessible` — Set method accessibility](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.setaccessible.php)

though you should ask yourself why you would want to do that. Usually parent classes that hide methods or properties from their children do so for a reason.

Comment: I do not want to do that, but just this questions came in my mind? And for curiosity I want to know the answer.

Comment: @Gaurav I am not sure I get what you want to do. Can you clarify please.

Comment: A child class inherits the type from parent class. Which means, child class MUST provide the same interface as the parent class, and possibly add new methods to it, but not substract. This is pretty much the reason why you can 'loosen' the modifiers, but not 'tighten' them.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is impossible. And not only in PHP.

Comment: can you give me any reason, why is it so?

Comment: In PHP, the accepted answer is correct. You can change the access modifiers if you change it to a looser one: protected => public.

Answer (score 2):

My own tests suggest that a child class can increase the visibility but not decrease it.

For example, suppose a parent class has a member variable declared as `private`. Then a child class can define the same member variable as either `private`, `protected, or`public`.

Similarly, if the parent member is declared as `protected`, then the child can can declare the member as `protected` or `public`.

Finally, if the parent declares the member as `public`, then the member must be `public` in all children.

Comment: @Gordon beat me to it. Sorry for the dupe answer. ;-)